# Express each of the following in terms of the standard basis $\varepsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Express each of the following in terms of the standard basis $\varepsilon$, $[z_1]_{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}7 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$
$[z_2]_{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}-6 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$

The basis $\beta$ is $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Finding what transformation maps $\beta$ to $\varepsilon$ I got
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{1}{5} \\ -\frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{5}\end{bmatrix}$$

Then finding what the coordinates are

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{5} & -\frac{1}{5} \\ -\frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{5}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}7 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$x=20 \space y= 5$$

and for the other set of coords, $\begin{bmatrix}-6 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, I got $$x=-15 \space y =0$$

I just wanted to make sure I answered the question properly because it can get confusing.